# XmlReader read continually

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a very large xml file. This is the simplified version of xml format.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Sender>
 <SenderID>571099948</SenderID>
 <Sponsors>
  <Sponsor>
    <SponsorID>TEST01</SponsorID>
    <Contracts>
      <Contract>
        <ContractID>000001</ContractID>
        <Member>
          <SSN>1111111111</SSN>
          <Gender>M</Gender>
          <Benefits>
            <Benefit BenefitType="AAA">
            </Benefit>
            <Benefit BenefitType="BBB">
            </Benefit>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <SSN>4444444444</SSN>
          <Gender>F</Gender>
          <Benefits>
            <Benefit BenefitType="AAA">
            </Benefit>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
      </Contract>
      <Contract>
        <ContractID>0000002</ContractID>
        <Member>
          <SSN>2222222222</SSN>
          <Gender>F</Gender>
          <Benefits>
            <Benefit BenefitType="CCC">
            </Benefit>
            <Benefit BenefitType="DDD">
            </Benefit>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
      </Contract>
      <Contract>
        <ContractID>0000003</ContractID>
        <Member>
          <SSN>333333333</SSN>
          <Gender>F</Gender>
          <Benefits> 
            <Benefit BenefitType="CCC">
            </Benefit>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
      </Contract>
    </Contracts>
  </Sponsor>
  <Sponsor>
    <SponsorID>TEST02</SponsorID>
    <Contracts>
      <Contract>
        <ContractID>0000011</ContractID>
        <Member>
          <SSN>1111111111</SSN>
          <Gender>M</Gender>
          <Benefits>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
      </Contract>
      <Contract>
        <ContractID>0000002</ContractID>
        <Member>
          <SSN>2222222222</SSN>
          <Gender>F</Gender>
          <Benefits>
          </Benefits>
        </Member>
      </Contract>
    </Contracts>
  </Sponsor>
</Sponsors>
</Sender>
```

I want get all information of contract node, as well as SponsorID from the parent node.  Here is the code to partially read xml file using XmlReader:

```
        static IEnumerable<XElement> SimpleStreamAxis(string inputUrl, string elementName)      
    {

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == elementName)
                        {
                            XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                            if (el != null)
                            {
                                yield return el;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                  
    }
```

Here is the issue.  I cannot use this, because the whole sponsor tree may be too large for the memory.

```
var sponsor = SimpleStreamAxis(file, "Sponsor");
```

I cannot use this either, because I cannot tell SponsorID with only Contract node info.

```
var contract = SimpleStreamAxis(file, "Contract");
```

Is there a way that I can read the SponsorID in Sponsor, move cursor forward, and read all the Contract nodes under this Sponsor, then move to next Sponsor and read SponsorID and its Contract nodes and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("SponsorID"))
        {
            string sponsorId = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            // process SponsorID
            Console.WriteLine(sponsorId);

            if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Contract"))
            {
                do
                {
                    XmlReader contractSubtree = xmlReader.ReadSubtree();
                    XElement contractElement = XElement.Load(contractSubtree);

                    // process Contract
                    Console.WriteLine(contractElement.Element("ContractID"));

                } while (xmlReader.ReadToNextSibling("Contract"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to dispose the `contractSubtree` before advancing the outer reader as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree?view=net-5.0#remarks):  *You should not perform any operations on the original reader until the new reader has been closed. This action is not supported and can result in unpredictable behavior.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done **assuming that `SponsorID` always precedes the `Contract` nodes**.

The basic idea is to read through the XML file until you find elements with the desired names `"SponsorID"` or`"Contract"`, then yield them for higher processing

```
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamNamedElements(XmlReader reader, IEnumerable<XName> names)
    {
        var nameSet = new HashSet<XName>(names);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && nameSet.Contains(XName.Get(reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI)))
            {
                XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                if (el != null)
                    yield return el;
            }
        }
    }
```

In cases where `SponsorID` is always present and precedes `Contract`, this will enumerate through these elements correctly.  However, if a sponsor ID is missing or out of order, the sponsor ID from a previous sponsor might get picked up.  This error can be trapped by restricting the scope of each "`SponsorID`" to the containing "`Sponsor`" element using [`ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    public static IEnumerable<XmlReader> StreamNamedSubtrees(XmlReader reader, IEnumerable<XName> names)
    {
        var nameSet = new HashSet<XName>(names);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && nameSet.Contains(XName.Get(reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI)))
            {
                var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                yield return subReader;
                ((IDisposable)subReader).Dispose(); // Be sure to advance to the end of the subtree if the caller did not.
            }
        }
    }
```

And then use it like:

```
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        {
            foreach (var subReader in StreamNamedSubtrees(reader, new[] { (XName)"Sponsor" }))
            {
                XElement sponsorID = null;
                foreach (var el in StreamNamedElements(subReader, new[] { (XName)"SponsorID", (XName)"Contract" }))
                {
                    if (el.Name == "SponsorID")
                    {
                        sponsorID = el;
                    }
                    else if (el.Name == "Contract")
                    {
                        if (sponsorID == null)
                            throw new InvalidOperationException();
                        // Example "higher processing"
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", sponsorID.Value, el.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with using a dictionary to keep sponsorID is that when the sponsorID changes, it always yields an extra return, with the new sponsorID and the old Contract.

Comment: @seattleSummer - answer updated to fix the problem you found.  Removing the dictionary actually made it simpler.

Comment: I do not see the point of using this loop.            foreach (var subReader in StreamNamedSubtrees(reader, new[] { (XName)"Sponsor" }))

Comment: I do not see the point of using the loop of subReader.  It maybe a typo.  I think you probably mean the inner loop use subReader instead of reader